# If a is nilpotent then a-1 and a+1 are invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> In a ring with unity prove that if $a$ is nilpotent, then $a+1$ and $a-1$ are both invertible.

In a ring with unity we have:
$1-a^n=(1-a)(1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1})$.
I believe this proves $a-1$ is invertible but I'm not sure why.

Then $1-(-1)^na^n=(1+a)(1-a+a^2-...+(-1)^{-1}a^{n-1})$.
Again I think this proves it but I don't know how.

I apologize as we haven't discussed nilpotent rings and yet I was asked to answer this question.

Comment: If $a$ is nilpotent, there is an $n$ such that $a^n=0$.  Apply that to your equation and you've found an explicit inverse to $a-1$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos in the linked, I do not understand the even and odd premise? Is this because an even $n$s would make $(-1)^n$ positive? Why is this a problem?

Comment: The even/odd split is a red herring.  just look at the approved answer

Answer (score 2):

Because $a$ nilpotent implies that $a^n=0$ for a given $n$ so $1-a^n=1=(1-a)(1+...+a^{n-1})$.